# Proving a type classed theorem in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, proof, jedit

I am to prove a triviality using type classes:

```
class order =
  fixes lesseq :: " 'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" (infix "≼" 50)
  assumes refl:    "x ≼ x"
      and trans:   "x ≼ y ⟹ y ≼ z ⟹ x ≼ z"
      and antisym: "x ≼ y ⟹ y ≼ x ⟹ x = y"
begin

  theorem "(myle:: ('b::order) ⇒ 'b ⇒ bool) x x"
  proof -
    show ?thesis by (rule refl)
  qed

end
```

Here, Isabelle/jEdit highlights `by (rule refl)` in pink and says

```
Failed to apply initial proof method⌂:
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. myle x x
```

What is the problem here? Otherwise the proof seems to go through.

Answer (score 3):

`myle` and `≼` are not the same function.

The type annotation `(myle:: ('b::order) ⇒ 'b ⇒ bool)` just states that `myle` is a function that takes two elements of type `'b` and returns a boolean and that `'b` is a type belonging to the `order` typeclass.

If you want to prove something about `≼` just use the same symbol or the name `lesseq`.

Comment: But why the type class does not enforce the refl, trans and antisym rules?

Comment: The typeclass does enforce the assumption, but only for the `≼` function, not for some other function with the same type.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you think about a function `sort :: ('b::order) list ⇒ 'b list`. It says that the sort functions works on elements that are comparable, not that `sort` itself is the comparison operator.